# Sorting a NON-SQL table column in a table containing data from SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, json, sorting

Below I have stripped down my code to a simplified version. I am storing SQL SELECT results for:

- last name (dlname)
- category (category)
- date this data was added to database (date_added)
- clients name (client)

I have appended an additional field outside the SQL SELECT called 'days_on_list'. This field shows the number of days since the data was added to the database, making the table output 5 columns of user data. ALL 5 COLUMNS ARE TO BE SORTABLE.

I am using server-side JSON and have successfully been able to display this to the table and perform sorting on 4 of the 5 columns. The **problem is that I am unable to sort the 'days_on_list' field as the PHP file containing the SQL code only allows me to sort the 4 fields from the select query**. Is there a way I can make 'days_on_list' column be sortable in the table? I know I can add this field to the sql table, but I would have to run a scheduled event on the server to update this daily (which I am not comfortable with).

**Is there another way to allow for this kind of flexible table sorting?**

*Sorry about the question title (may be confusing), I was having trouble putting this into a question.*

```js
/*SQL CODE ABOVE HERE STORES SELECT RETURNS IN $result*/
$cart = array();
$i = 0; //index the entries
// get variables from sql result.
if ($num_rows > 0) { //if table is populated...

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    //calculate days on list by getting the number of days from 
    //the 'date_added' to today 
    $date1 = date_create($row['date_added']);
    $today = date_create(date("d-m-Y"));
    $interval = date_diff($date1, $today);
    $doty = $interval - > format("%a");

    $cart[$i] = array(
      "dlname" => htmlspecialchars($row['dlname']),
      "category" => htmlspecialchars($row['category']),
      "date_added" => htmlspecialchars($row['date_added']),
      "client" => htmlspecialchars($row['client']),
      "days_on_list" => $doty, //date_added to now
    );
    $i = $i + 1; //add next row
  }

  //encoding the PHP array
  $json_server_pagination_data = array(
    "total" => intval($num_rows),
    "rows" => $cart, //array data
  );
}

echo json_encode($json_server_pagination_data);
```

Comment: When I sort the days_on_list column it returns an empty table, and the data returns when I sort one of the other columns. I thought that as long as the table has access to all the data within the json output then sorting by days_on_list would behave exactly like the other columns.

Comment: I am in a weird situation where for my sorting to work for the 4 columns (all apart from days_on_list), I add an ORDER BY [column here] within the SQL query. But because the days_on_list exists outside the query, I am getting an empty table

Comment: WOW! It worked! Thank you so much friend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `days_on_list` is calculated by simply comparing `date_added` to the current date, sorting by `days_on_list` should have exactly the reverse effect as sorting by `date_added`.

In other words, you don't actually need to sort by `days_on_list`. If the user selects `days_on_list` as the sort column, just use `ORDER BY date_added` (in the opposite direction ASC/DESC).